# UILabel remove bottom margin

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, margin

I am having a trouble with a UILabel.
I am trying to have the UILabel so that there is no margin at all in the container.
I tried different things, like sizeToFit, boundsToRect and others, but never got the solution so far.

Here is my code:

```
UILabel* saveLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
saveLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
saveLabel.text = "USER     SAVE";
saveLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
saveLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
[saveLabel sizeToFit];
```

When I add this to my view I would expect that the border at the bottom (from the border) touch the letter of the labels, but there is a space in between.

I have attached a picture of the bottom effect if you want to see.
http://oi62.tinypic.com/n62b0w.jpg

I really cant understand why this margin is there and how to get rid of it.
All the other margin, top, left and right are fine, just the bottom one.

Any help on this would be very appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The frame includes space for lower case letters like g and y which 'descend' below the text's baseline. In your case, you're only using uppercase letters, so you may wish to remove the descender portion of the frame. You can access the height of the descender via `saveLabel.font.descender` and then subtract that from the height of the fitted frame.

```
[saveLabel sizeToFit];
saveLabel.frame = CGRectMake(saveLabel.frame.origin.x
                             saveLabel.frame.origin.y,
                             saveLabel.frame.size.width,
                             saveLabel.frame.size.height - saveLabel.font.descender);
```

The following article has a good diagram: 
https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/

Comment: genius, this is exactly my issue, now everything get fit properly. Thanks very much wish I could vote, but as I am newbies looks like I cannot add a vote yet. I will select you as the answer. thanks

Comment: Seems like when I subtract the descender from the frame's height, the UILabel is not adjusting the position of the text, and the top of the text is getting cutoff, rather than removing the space from the bottom of the UILabel.